# What is a platform-agnostic powershell way to remove nodes from large xml files?

Tags: xml, powershell

I have 90mb xml files that I'd like to process on Linux Mac & Windows. They have hundreds of "Label" nodes like this:

```
<net.rptools.maptool.model.Label> ...few children... </net.rptools.maptool.model.Label>
```

I want to process the files to remove all these Label nodes. However, it might be better to remove their parents, which seems to be a few

```
<labels class="linked-hash-map"> ...many megs of Label children... </labels>
```

I won't know which is better until I attempt to load the xml back into the application.

I've seen powershell XML processing examples that seem to use Windows specific APIs. What might be the preferred platform-agnostic API and style for deleting nodes from large-ish files?

Comment: I'm a bit puzzled by seeing "powershell" and "platform-agnostic" in the same question. Surely it's either Powershell, or it's platform-agnostic, but it can't be both?

Comment: @MichaelKay, I think the intent is to find a single method that works as-is on all platforms of interest, which [PowerShell (Core)](https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell), the cross-platform PowerShell edition, indeed can provide.

Comment: OK, I guess it depends on what you mean by "platform". I think of .NET and Java as platforms.

Comment: @MichaelKay, I see. I'd say that in common usage the term "platform" (without additional qualification) refers to the host _OS_. However, the lines are blurry: according to Wikipedia, .NET is a "software framework", and Java a "software platform".

Comment: It's turtles all the way down.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you don't want any fancy api and just plain access to the xml as an object it is as simple as casting the xml to an [xml] object

```
$xmldoc = [xml](Get-Content 'c:\temp\books.xml' -Raw)
```

or

```
$xmldoc = [xml]@"
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
   <book id="bk101">
      <author>Gambardella, Matthew</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
      <genre>Computer</genre>
      <price>44.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-10-01</publish_date>
      <description>An in-depth look at creating applications 
      with XML.</description>
   </book>
   <book id="bk102">
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
      <genre>Fantasy</genre>
      <price>5.95</price>
      <publish_date>2000-12-16</publish_date>
      <description>A former architect battles corporate zombies, 
      an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen 
      of the world.</description>
   </book>
</catalog>
"@
```

Then you can access or modify the xml through its properties

```
PS C:\temp> $xmldoc.catalog.book

id           : bk101
author       : Gambardella, Matthew
title        : XML Developer's Guide
genre        : Computer
price        : 44.95
publish_date : 2000-10-01
description  : An in-depth look at creating applications
                     with XML.

id           : bk102
author       : Ralls, Kim
title        : Midnight Rain
genre        : Fantasy
price        : 5.95
publish_date : 2000-12-16
description  : A former architect battles corporate zombies,
                     an evil sorceress, and her own childhood to become queen
                     of the world.
```

If you modify you can write modified object back to file using

```
$xmldoc.Save("C:\temp\testout.xml")
```

Comment: That's pretty neat.

Comment: Please use `$xml = [xml]::new(); $xml.Load('c:\temp\books.xml')` instead of the `Get-Content` method, because the latter does not pay attention to XML encodings. For background see https://github.com/PowerShell/PowerShell/issues/14508

Answer (score 1):

I went with something like the example below. The application would not let me delete "labels" nodes, and the "net.rptools.maptool.model.Label" nodes were children of "entry" nodes.
So I used `SelectNodes` with an XPath expression to find all "entry" nodes under "labels" parents, and then removed them from the parent:

```powershell
#!/usr/bin/env pwsh
Set-StrictMode -Version Latest
 
$branch = Get-Location 
$contentFileIn = "$branch\content.xml"
$contentFileOut = "$branch\content_pruned.xml"

$xmlDoc = [xml]::new()
$xmlDoc.Load($contentFileIn)

$entryNodes = $xmlDoc.SelectNodes("//labels/entry")
foreach ($entryNode in $entryNodes){
        $entryNode.ParentNode.RemoveChild($entryNode)
}
$xmldoc.Save($contentFileOut)
```

Answer (score 0):

Removing elements with a given name is easy using XSLT, which is about as platform-agnostic as you can get. In XSLT 3.0 it's simply:

```
<xsl:transform version="3.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:mode on-no-match="shallow-copy"/>
<xsl:template match="label"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

XSLT 1.0 is more widely available but slightly more verbose:

```
<xsl:transform version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:template match="*">
   <xsl:copy><xsl:apply-templates/></xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="label"/>
</xsl:transform>
```

By way of explanation, in both cases you're saying that by default, elements are recursively shallow-copied to the result, except for label elements, for which no output is generated (i.e. they are deleted).

Comment: I tried to use XslCompiledTransform, with System.Xml.XmlWriter, but XmlWriter complained that my documents were not well formed, and setting the ConformanceLevel to either Fragment or Auto did not help. No other parsers complained about invalid XML, so I bailed and used SelectNodes and RemoveChild.

Comment: You did something wrong, but from that information I'm afraid I can't tell you what.